# Why does !document.body return False?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking at the [source code for JQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js)  and tried to understand how their:
`$(document).ready()`
function works.

And on row 407 I found this part:
`if ( !document.body ) {`
which seams to be a key to determine if the document is loaded or not.

**What I wonder is:**
why does:
`!document.body`
return `False`?

while:
`document.body`
returns: `[object HTMLBodyElement]`
[You can try it here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_body_innerhtml) just remove the first: `.innerHTML`

(I couldn't find a proper answer with Google after an hour of searching & reading, so now I hope there are some professionals here that can help me, thanks!)

Edit: yes I know `!document.body` comes from JavaScript instead of JQuery, in the end JQuery is built with JavaScript code.

Comment: browser compatability reasons iirc. a relic from oldIE

Comment: Each browser is different.

Comment: Doesn't the comment hint to why? Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `Make sure body exists, at least, in case IE gets a little overzealous (ticket #5443).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have understood what happens and what I misunderstood.
I originally only expected 2 different states (true/false) but in fact there are 4 different states, as shown in this table:

```
| Page loading state    |       document.body       | !document.body |
|=======================|===========================|================|
| Before page is loaded |            ?              | !false -> true |
|-----------------------|---------------------------|----------------|
| After page is loaded  | [object HTMLBodyElement]  | !true -> false |
```

My error was that I only looked at the "after loaded"-row and extected to see `true` in the `document.body` column.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking has nothing to do with jQuery. It is in fact Javascript:

document.body always returns true if the body is loaded. So !document.body means if the body has not loaded yet, then take some action.

According to the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body), the property works with earlier version of most of the browsers

[image].

Comment: When I try: `document.body` on W3Schools website I don't get a `False`/ `True` answer, I get a `False`/`[object HTMLBodyElement]` answer.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, because of type conversion. The `!` operator does a type conversion from the object to the boolean "true" value, then negates it to the "false" value.

Formally, from the [ECMA-262 Ecmascript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html):

> 12.5.9 Logical NOT Operator ( ! )#
>
> ```
> Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> Let oldValue be ToBoolean(? GetValue(expr)).
> If oldValue is true, return false.
> Return true.
> ```

and

> 7.1.2 ToBoolean ( argument )#
>
> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts argument to a value of type
>   Boolean according to Table 10: Table 10: ToBoolean Conversions
>
> ```
> Argument Type     Result 
> Undefined     Return false. 
> Null          Return false.
> Boolean       Return argument. 
> Number        Return false if argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise return true. 
> String        Return false if argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>                       otherwise return true. 
> Symbol        Return true. 
> Object        Return true.
> ```